# Whoever objects to me going to the Convention ought to state his position promptly

Tags: grammaticality

A.Whoever objects to me
B.Whomever objects to me 
C.Whomever objects to my 
D.Whoever objects to my

What will be the right answer and why??

Comment: [What is the right answer, not "will be" here]. Also, we do not answer homework questions. You can find exercises with who/ whom and whoever and whomever on the internet. If we give you the answer, you have not done the work. :)

Comment: I tried several times but faied that's why I asked here

Comment: ***Whomever*** is little-used today in ***any*** contexts (we usually just use ***whoever*** regardless of whether it'[s the syntactic *subject* or *object* today). But neither are particularly likely in your *exact* context, where the idiomatic standard form is ***Anyone who** objects to me [marrying this woman should speak up now, or forever hold their peace]*. You might hear wierdo versions like ***Whomsoever objects...*** in the context of certain religious ceremonies, but that's a *deliberately* "archaic" usage that wouldn't usually turn up in "natural" contexts.

Comment: Ok, I have given you an answer because you are a newbie but please show your own efforts under the question next time. These are just like who and whom.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

**Whoever, the pronoun, is for the subject of a sentence for verbs that do not take an indirect object pronoun**:

- Whoever stole the money should put it back. [test: steal money **from someone**]
- Whoever said that is nuts. [test: say something **to someone**].

You don't say: steal me money or say me something, so whoever does not work.

Whomever is a direct object pronoun, for verbs that take a direct object pronoun.

- He **likes them** because they are nice people. Them is an direct object pronoun after the verb like:

**Whomever he likes** must be nice.

- They would **like whomever** you tell them to like.
- We **see them** in the evenings. The **verb see takes a direct object pronoun**.
- **Whomever you see** in the evenings should be on time.

**They object to me** going. No direct object after the verb object. Ergo, it's a subject.

- John objects to me going.
- Whoever objects to me going should say so.

That said, these rules are not strictly followed and we tend to use whoever as the subject pronoun regardless of the standard usage.

Example: Whoever you saw last night must have been very late.

rather than: Whomever you saw last night must have been very late. [the standard grammar way to say it.]

So take the verb and see if it can be followed by a direct object pronoun. If it can, use whomever, if it cannot use whoever.

Comment: Is it right to say  "whoever objects to my" but still I am in confusion with pronoun "MY" as I know  after preposition "object form is used"  plz clear my confusion

Comment: Is it right to say"Write to me " so why you use here " object to my" why not "me"

Comment: I answered this question like this " Whoever objects to "My" going" but my teacher declared  it "wrong"

Comment: Whoever objects to my going or me going// are **both correct**.